# How to detect or avoid edited javascript from client browser?

Tags: javascript

i'm new to use javascript 
now i can edit my javascript code from browser using firebug. 
any idea, to detect or avoid edited javascript from client browser ??

Comment: That shouldn't bother you. cause that doesn't change your source code

Comment: Even if someone edit's the javascript code it doesn't get saved.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you mean by "avoiding" edited javascript - are you looking for ways to suppress execution of such javascript?

Comment: You'll have to use cryptography, or just rethink your logic.

Answer (score 8):

You can't.

You can (and should) use server side code to check that any data sent to the server is sane, but you can't do anything to stop people sending whatever data they like.

Comment: I believe he wants to prevent anyone from editing it, client-side. I don't think he's sending it back to the server...

Comment: @Cerbrus - The most common reason for worrying about JavaScript being editable on the client comes from a desire to perform form input validation (and the like) with JavaScript. The solution is to do that on the server, and not the client. Hence the note in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to prevent people from tinkering with your js in the browser, since js is sent as-is, from the server.

You can however [obfuscate](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/) your js to make it slightly harder to edit. ([Another link](http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm))

Comment: yes i know that's not change my code, but for example i set my permissions setting from a button. if user have permission the button is enable,but if user does not have permission the button is disable.but everybody can enable my button from firebug.. :(

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing you can do against that. This is why you should always verify the data a user returns to the server, like Quentin said in his answer.

Comment: But i'm using EXTJS, when i set disable my button from id property(Ext.getCmp('mybuttonid').disable()),i can set enable my button from firebug.. but if i set disable my button by var name (myButton.disable()) and remove id property from my button config,i can't edit my button from firebug, so now i think user can't edit my button or every component config by var name,, that's right??